# How to update WordPress plugin readme.txt description page without triggering a plugin update?

Tags: plugins, updates, readme

Is it possible to update the readme.txt file for a plugin without releasing a new plugin version update?

Comment: You can update the readme.txt without a change on the plugin version, that's possible and without problems. You should only switch the plugin version if you have change(s) in the source code, not the readme.txt. This is typically if you would change the 'tested up' version for WP inside the readme.txt to list this value on the plugin page.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the plugin description (and other sections), it all comes from the current version README.TXT file.

So if you upload a changed version of README.TXT to the current version's repository (not changing the repository version number), the newly updated README.TXT file information is shown on the page.

This is great for updating the 'tested to' version numbers, when you didn't make any code changes to the plugin.

More info [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/) (and other links from there).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, If you don't update the plugin version, it will not trigger the plugin update. I have done this few times for my plugins, and it works, for as long as the version has not changed.

Comment: Are you saying it will work or it will not work? Your first and second sentence seem to contradict one-another.

Comment: If nothing was changed in the WP.org processing in the past 6 months, it will work if the plugin version has not been changed.